Auto complete for Python files in VS Code does not work for sub directories
End goal
Setting up autocomplete for my self wrriten lib in VS Code for python files that will eventually run in Autodesk Revit.
Project Structure
├── my_directory
│   ├── script1.py
│   └── subdirectory
│       └── script2.py
└── lib
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── example.py
    └── converter
        ├── __init__.py
        └── converter_script.py

What I've done

creating .env file in the project's root directory
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}/lib

Creating settings.json in the project's root directory
{
 "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",

 "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
     "${workspaceFolder}/lib"
 ]

}

Adding the route of lib directory to Environment Variables globally in my pc


The problem
I want to import and use the code from lib inside scripts that are located in my_directory. Right now I get autocomplete AND the code executes properly in Revit ONLY for example.py , but when trying to import something from converter_script.py - There is no autocomplete and I get an error when trying to run the code.
ImportError: No module named converter_script

I added an import to the functions into __init__.py file inside the converter directory.
How can I solve it so that I will get autocomplete and the code will run, without having to change and reconfigure files every time I add new scripts and sub directories in lib?
script1.py content
from example import test_print                # Works
from converter_script import converter_print  # Does not work
converter_print()
test_print()
print('hola mundo')


You might want to setup you project like this: script you start directly into the root, packages as (one-level) folders with __init__.py.

Have you tried from lib.converter.converter_script import converter_print? And make sure that the __init__.py file is correctly placed in both the lib and converter directories.

I manged to make it work by adding manually to .env and settings.json the a path to the new script file (of course while creating __init__.py for it in the new sub directory). Not the solution I wanted, but it works for now. I guess I can write a script that searches and detects new scripts in lib, but then again I'd have to run it manually each time...

You could also try to add "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["path/to/folder"] to your settings.json to achieve the same goal.
